# How to undo the changes I made in a git branch?

Tags: git, cloud9-ide

After creating a new git branch, I removed some files. Then I decided I wanted to discard these changes and removed the branch without merging. However the files are not back. What should I do?

The steps I followed:

- `git checkout -b newbranche`
- I'm working in the IDE Cloud9 and removed some files, including a model and migration files.
- `git checkout master` and `git branch -D newbranche`
- I thought this should undo all the changes/deleted files. I restarted the IDE and also refreshed its explorer (there where you see all the files and folders) but the files I removed are no longer there. How can this be since I didn't merge the changes?
- While in the master branch, if I enter `git status` I get an overview of all the deleted files under "Changes not staged for commit". It also says: use "git checkout -- ..." to discard changes in working directory.

How can I fully undo the changes/deleted files I made in the 'newbranche' branch?

Comment: Which command did you use to delete the file?

Comment: If the files you deleted were being tracked by git and they existed on the `master` branch, they would exist after you did what you did. My guess is that they were not being tracked by git so you just deleted files on your system, in which case you can't recover them unless you have a backup somewhere.

Comment: In the IDE Cloud9 I just right-clicked the file in the IDE's explorer and selected delete.

Comment: The files were tracked. If I go to bitbucket the deleted files are still there under source for the master branch. It seems more like as if I deleted the files in the master branch (given the output I mentioned for `git status` while in the master branch) but have not yet committed these changes.

Comment: Then just do `git checkout master; git reset --hard origin/master`. NB: this will undo any commits you have made since `origin/master` and will remove any changes to tracked files you may have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say it is a case where you need to be very careful (this will not delete untracked added files, but will undo any modifying changes or deletions)

```
git fetch
git reset --hard origin/master
```